# DAX to find percent of total based on filter (regardless of view)

Tags: excel-formula, powerpivot, dax

How do I create DAX that finds the percent of incidents that are Status=Closed based on row view

Total Incidents = Count of CREATED_DATE

I tried following Measure both gave error

```
`% Closed:=if(Table1[STATUS]="Closed",[Count of CREATED_DATE],0)/[Count of CREATED_DATE]`
```

and

`% Closed2:=DIVIDE(if(Table1[STATUS]="Closed",[Count of CREATED_DATE],0),[Count of CREATED_DATE],0)`

Sample data from Power Pivot.

[image]

Here is my table

[image]

Here is what I wish to create. Please note, the % of Closed Incidents to Total should change based on how I filter the power-pivot, i.e. if I filter to include ONLY closed incidents, then naturally the % should be 100%

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the `Calculate` function, which allows for calculations under different contexts.  Think of it as excel's sumif function but a bit more powerful.

So for example the below, which would do a count of the BBL rows where the table1 status is closed.  Note for count the column has to be a number or date.

```
Closed Count:=CALCULATE( COUNT( Table1[BBL]), Table1[STATUS] = "Closed")
```

Then you can do your divide.  Keep in mind that not putting the alternative result, means that in a divide by zero error power pivot will return NULL.  The advantage being that if a all measures in a row evaluates to null it will be suppressed in the pivot.

```
Total Incidents:=COUNT( Table1[BBL])

Closed %:=DIVIDE( [Closed Count], [Total Incidents])
```